# Does Safari with userinfo in URL ignore target="_blank"

Tags: safari, userinfo

For our website, we want all links to open in new tabs. Our QA specialist tried a URL like https://username@google.com and the page was open in the same tab. I am guessing that Safari does this for security reason, but I cannot find proof. Can someone give more context or links I can share with my team?